# Eloquent complex query

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I need sql query, but i need to use Eloquent:

```
"SELECT * FROM Pass WHERE serial_number=$registered_serial_numbers AND (updated_at IS NULL OR updated_at >= $passesUpdatedSince)"
```

I try but have error:

```
$registered_passes = Pass::where('serial_number', $registered_serial_numbers)->where("updated_at IS NULL OR updated_at >= $passesUpdatedSince")->get();
```

How should i do it in Eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing it:

1) using whereRaw()

```
$registered_passes = Pass::whereIn('serial_number', $registered_serial_numbers)->whereRaw('updated_at IS NULL OR updated_at >= ?', $passesUpdatedSince)->get();
```

2) using a closure to do the AND (OR)

```
$registered_passes = Pass::whereIn('serial_number', $registered_serial_numbers)->where(function($query){
$query->whereNull('updated_at')->orWhere('updated_at', '>=', $passesUpdatedSince);})->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

Have a look at the "Parameter Grouping" section

Answer (score 0):

<s>The query should be something like this:</s>

`$registered_passes = Pass::where("updated_at", $passesUpdatedSince)->whereIn('serial_number',$registered_serial_numbers)->get();`

You use `whereIn` method for `where in` clause and make sure `$registered_serial_numbers` is an array of values.

My bad, misread it. If you are fine with serial number, just do a `whereRaw` like this:

```
$registered_passes = Pass::where('serial_number',$registered_serial_numbers)->whereRaw('updated_at IS NULL OR updated_at >= ?', $passesUpdatedSince)->get();
```

Comment: i have no problem with serial_number, problem with "updated_at IS NULL OR updated_at >= $passesUpdatedSince"

Comment: Yeah of course, just pasted the same thing in there. Edited.